# O que é CGI e qual é sua finalidade?

Tags: cgi

O que é o CGI (common gateway interface) e o que ele faz?

É uma tecnologia antiga?

Existem outras alternativas a ele? Se sim, quais?

Comment: ready to learn something new.

Comment: +1. Também quero saber, mas não quero pesquisar no Google. E corrigi o `Exitem`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### Common Gateway Interface

**CGI** (sigla em inglês para Common Gateway Interface), em português , Interface Comum de Porta de entrada.

**Interface**: elemento que proporciona uma ligação física ou lógica entre dois sistemas ou partes de um sistema que não poderiam ser conectados diretamente.

### Visão Geral

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Geralmente, o servidor *HTTP* tem um diretório (pasta), que é designado como uma coleção de documentos(arquivos), que podem ser enviados para navegadores da Web ligados a este servidor. Por exemplo, se o servidor Web tem o nome de domínio `exemplo.com` , e sua coleção de documentos é armazenado em `/usr/local/apache/htdocs` no sistema de arquivos local, em seguida, o servidor web irá responder a um pedido de `http://exemplo.com/index.html` enviando para o navegador o arquivo `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.html`.

**CGI** estende esse sistema, permitindo ao proprietário do servidor Web designar um diretório dentro da coleção de documento contendo scripts executáveis ​​(ou arquivos binários) em vez de páginas pré-escritas, isto é conhecido como um diretório `CGI`. Por exemplo, `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/cgi-bin` poderia ser designado como um diretório `CGI` no servidor Web. Se um navegador da Web solicita a *URL* que aponta para um arquivo dentro do diretório `CGI` (por exemplo, `http://exemplo.com/cgi-bin/printenv.pl`), em vez de simplesmente enviar o arquivo ( `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/cgi-bin/printenv.pl`) para o navegador web, o servidor *HTTP* executa o script especificado e passa a saída do script para o navegador da web. Ou seja, qualquer coisa que o script envia a saída padrão é passado para o cliente Web em vez de ser mostrado na tela em uma janela de terminal.

### Estrutura geral de scripts CGI:

- Leitura e descodificação de dados (e/ou campos de informação de um
  pacote *HTTP*);
- Processamento dos dados (gravar informação em bases de dados,
  realizar cálculos, recuperar dados);
- Criação de uma página Web com os resultados produzidos.

### Exemplos de aplicação de CGI's

- Processamento de dados submetidos através de formulários;
- Servir de interface com a bases de dados, fazendo a conversão da
  transação de `HTML` para `SQL` e formatar em `HTML` as respostas obtidas,
  enviando em seguida os resultados para o cliente;
- Converter dados do sistema para `HTML` e retornar o resultado para o
  cliente;
- Criação de documentos personalizados;
- Gerir contadores de acesso;
- Processamento de mapas.

### Métodos de transmissão

O protocolo *HTTP*, utiliza vários métodos de manipulação e organização dos dados.  Os dois métodos mais utilizados para submeter dados de formulários são o **GET** e o **POST**. Ambos os métodos transferem dados do browser para o servidor, a maior diferença entre eles é a maneira como a informação é passada para o programa `CGI`:

**GET**

***CGI chamada através do método GET***

O browser acrescenta um "**?**" ao URL especificado no atributo **ACTION**,  e os valores codificados;

```
http://exemplo.com/cgi-bin/registra.pl?login=guest
```

O servidor ao receber um *URL* com uma *query-string*, chama o programa `cgi` identificado na 1ª parte do URL (antes do `'?'`) e guarda a parte depois do `'?'` na variável de ambiente [QUERY_STRING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)  (a `string` de consultas contida na *URL* após o `'?'`) . Supondo que o utilizador digitou "guest" no campo login, quando o botão *submit* é clicado, o browser envia, ao servidor, um pedido do tipo:

```
GET /cgi-bin/registra.pl?login='guest' HTTP/1.0 
Accept: www/source
Accept: text/html
Accept: image.gif
User-Agent: Lynx/2.4 libwww/2.14
From: shisshir@bu.edu
```

O pedido `GET` identifica o documento a enviar (cgi-bin/registra.pl). Desde que o servidor esteja configurado para reconhecer todos os ficheiros no diretório `cgi-bin` como sendo um programa `cgi`, executa o programa em vez de enviar o documento diretamente ao browser, além disso coloca a *string* `login='guest'` na variável de ambiente *QUERY_STRING*.

[Fonte](https://web.fe.up.pt/%7Egoii2000/M9/exp_get.htm)

***Programa CGI capaz de gerir esta informação***

```
#! /usr/local/bin/tclsh
/* Diz ao servidor para correr o interpretador tcl localizado no directório /usr/local/bin/ para executar o programa cgi/*

puts "Content-type: text/plain", "\n\n"
set query_string $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}
set par [split $query_string = ] 
set field_name [lindex $par 0]
set command [lindex $par 1] 
if {$command == "guest"} {
puts "usr/local/bin/guest"
} elsif {$command == "mgi"} {
puts "usr/ucb/mgi"
} else {
puts "usr/local/bin/outro";
}
exit(0);
```

([Variáveis de Ambiente nos Scripts CGI](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/SSSHTQ_8.1.0/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_8.1.0/webtop/wip/reference/web_cust_envvariablesincgiscripts.html))

**POST**

Se utilizar o método Post, o pedido enviado ao servidor seria do tipo:

```
POST /cgi-bin /registra.pl HTTP/1.0
.
. (informação do cabeçalho)
.
Content-length: 11
login=guest
```

***Programa CGI capaz de gerir esta informação***

```
#! /usr/local/bin/tclsh
set size_of_form_information $env(CONTENT_LENGTH)
set form_info [read stdin $size_of_form_information]
set par [split $form_info = ]
set field_name [lindex $par 0]
set command [lindex $par 1]

puts "Content-type: text/plain", "\n\n"
if {$command == "guest"} {
puts "usr/local/bin/guest"
} elsif {$command == "mgi"} {
puts "usr/ucb/mgi"
} else {
puts "usr/local/bin/outro";
}
exit(0);
```

O programador de *CGI's* não consegue controlar por qual método o programa vai ser chamado. Assim os scripts são geralmente escritos para suportar ambos os métodos.

```
#! /usr/local/bin/tclsh
set request_method $env(REQUEST_METHOD)
if {$request_method =="GET"}{
et form_info $env(QUERY_STRING)
} else {
set size_of_form_information $env(CONTENT_LENGTH)
set form_info [read stdin $size_of_form_information]
}
```

Os dados introduzidos em um formulário fazem parte do corpo da mensagem enviada para o servidor.

Enquanto o método `GET` passa a informação através de variáveis de ambiente , o POST envia os dados para o programa `CGI` através do standard input (entrada padrão,[stdio.h](https://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/examples/stdio_8h-source.html)), como uma string de comprimento especificado na variável de ambiente `CONTENT_LENGTH`;

Faz 2 ligações ao servidor, uma para contactar o servidor e outra para enviar os parâmetros. Em outras palavras, se o servidor receber um pedido de um formulário usando o `POST`, ele sabe que tem que continuar "à espera" do resto da informação.

***Vantagens/Desvantagens***

A vantagem do `GET` é que permite aceder ao programa *CGI* com uma query sem utilizar um formulário, basicamente estamos a passar parâmetros para um programa.
Exemplo: `<A HREF="/cgi-bin/program.pl?user=Larry%20Bird&age=35&pass=testing"> Programa CGI </A>`

A maior desvantagem do `GET` é a falta de segurança e o facto de ter de haver algum cuidado para que o browser ou o servidor não trunquem a informação que exceda o número de caracteres permitido.

A maior vantagem do método `POST` é o tamanho da query poder ser ilimitada. Para obter informação através do método `POST`, o programa *CGI* lê do standard input, por essa razão não é possivel aceder à *CGI* sem utilizar um formulário.

### História

Levando em conta a velocidade com a qual as inovações acontecem, *CGI* pode ser considerado antigo, levando em consideração a criação do computador pode se dizer que está na meia-idade.

Em 1993, a equipe o National Center for Supercomputing Applications (NCSA),escreveu uma especificação para chamar executáveis ​​de linha de comando na www-talk lista de emails. No entanto, NCSA não hospeda a especificação.

Outros desenvolvedores adotaram a especificação, e tem sido um padrão para servidores web desde então. Um grupo presidido por Ken Coar começou em novembro de 1997 um trabalho para obter a definição NCSA de *CGI* mais formalmente definida.  Este trabalho resultou em [**RFC3875**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875) , que especifica a versão `CGI 1.1.` Expressamente mencionados na *RFC* são os contribuintes que se segue:

Rob McCool (autor do NCSA HTTPd Web Server )
John Franks (autor do Web Server GN)
Ari Luotonen (o desenvolvedor do CERN httpd servidor Web)
Tony Sanders (autor do servidor Plexus Web)
George Phillips (mantenedor do servidor Web na University of British Columbia ).

Como alternativa pode considerar:

- [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI)
- [PSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSGI)(Perl Web Server Gateway Interface)
- [Rack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_(web_server_interface)) (web server interface)
- [WSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface)(Web Server Gateway Interface)

Exemplo simples de um script CGI

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="add.cgi" method="POST">
   Coloque os dois números:<br />
   Primeiro número: <input type="text" name="num1" /><br />
   Segundo número: <input type="text" name="num2" /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Arquivo add.cgi

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

input_data=cgi.FieldStorage()

print 'Content-Type:text/html' #Envia o tipo HTML
print                          #deixa uma linha vazia entre o head e body
print '<h1>Resutados</h1>'
try:
  num1=int(input_data["num1"].value)
  num2=int(input_data["num2"].value)
except:
  print '<p>Desculpe não podemos converter os campos em números (integers).</p>'
  return 1
sum=num1+num2
print '<p>{0} + {1} = {2}</p>'.format(num1, num2, sum)
```

Fontes: [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)/[CGI completo](https://web.fe.up.pt/%7Egoii2000/M9/cgi.htm)

Comment: Opa, estamos melhorando o nivel das respostas. vejamos o que vai rolar até daqui a uns 5 dias pra ver quem leva o bônus :) - de qq forma, já leve um +1.

Comment: +1 pela excelente  resposta :)

Comment: @drmcarvalho  com tutores como vcs o difícil fica fácil..;)

Comment: Muito boa resposta +1, só corrigi algumas coisas, como excessos de linhas brancas não usadas e este script `print '<p>{0} + {1} = {2}</p>'.format(num1, num2, sum)'` que tinha um apostrofo sobrando, aproveitei pra "aportuguesar" os comentários no código em python

Answer (score 24):

## O que é o CGI(common gateway interface) e o que ele faz?

CGI(Common Gateway Interface) é uma tecnologia que permite gerar páginas dinâmicas com interação entre scripts de *Servidores HTTP* com *Gateway Scripts* e *Programas* através de parâmetros. Sendo assim **Scripts CGI** são os pequenos programas que interpretam esses parâmetros e geram uma página depois de os processar.

> Porém o *uso do **CGI** não é muito seguro*, tendo em mente que é preciso tomar algumas precauções de seguranças. Logo abaixo será discutido sobre que precauções de segurança tomar baseado em algumas regras dos programas **CGI** após a explicação de como o **CGI** funciona.

### Como funciona?

**Exemplo:**

- O CLIENTE(Browser) solicita uma URL ao SERVIDOR
- A URL solicitada é referente a um CGI, portanto o SERVIDOR executa o CGI
- o CGI trabalha interagindo com outras aplicações do sistema, recupera dados destas aplicações e retorna o resultado ao SERVIDOR
- O SERVIDOR envia os dados para o CLIENTE, que formata o resultado e apresenta ao usuário

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Para que usar CGI?

Com o **CGI**, seu servidor pode acessar informações que não estão de uma forma legível para o cliente (ex. SQL database), e age como gateway entre ambos para produzir alguma coisa que o cliente possa usar. Gateways podem ser usadas para uma variedade de propositos, os mais comuns são **manipulação de ISINDEX e requisição de formulário para HTTP**.

### Exemplos do uso de CGI:

- Converter páginas de manual de sistemas para HTML e enviar o resultado HTML para o cliente.
- Fazer interface com WAIS e banco de dados archie, convertendo os resultados para HTML e enviando o resultado para o cliente.
- Permitir ao usuário realimentar seu servidor atraves de um formulário HTML e um decodificador acompanhando o **CGI**.

**Você pode estar escrevendo estes CGI's através de gateways que podem ser escritos em qualquer liguagem que permita ser executado no sistema, tais como:**

- C/C++
- Fortran
- Perl
- TCL
- Unix Shell
- Visual Basic
- Apple Script

### Quais são as principais regras dos programas CGI?

Programas CGI, ou scripts, são programas executáveis que podem ser executados por si mesmo (o que não é uma maneira segura). Portanto existem algumas precauções de segurança que necessitam ser implementadas quando utilizando programas CGI.

As principais regras são:

- O script CGI tem que estar em um lugar determinado pelo servidor para os scripts CGI ou tem que ter um sufixo especial, que o servidor está configurado para reconhecer como um script CGI legal.

> A maioria dos sistemas armazena scripts CGI em um diretório raiz do servidor HTTP, chamado **cgi-bin**, que é configurado de tal forma que, somente determinados usuários de confiança, possam gravar nele. Isto evita problemas óbvios de segurança, que surgem ao se permitir que usuários anônimos remotos executem qualquer coisa no sistema.
> **Exemplo:** `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/cgi-bin`

- O script pode recolher seus parâmetros, da entrada padrão (via teclado), das [variáveis de ambientes](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/SSSHTQ_8.1.0/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_8.1.0/webtop/wip/reference/web_cust_envvariablesincgiscripts.html) ou de ambas.
- O script deve dar como saída, um dos três **tipos de cabeçalho padrão**, como uma string de texto normal. Sendo os três tipos:

  - **CONTEXT_TYPE:** O tipo de conteúdo se refere a qualquer tipo de dado MIME que seja aceito pelo servidor.
    Os tipos comuns incluem *texto/html*, *texto/simples* e *dados/gif*.
    Como o browser/servidor não pode deduzir este tipo de arquivo, a partir de uma localização ou sufixo de nome de arquivo, este título informará ao browser que tipo de dados esperar e como usá-lo.

    Formato: tipo/tipo
  - **LOCATION:** Aponta para um documento em algum outro lugar do servidor.
    Permite que você redirecione pedidos para documentos, baseando-se em algum critério enviado por um formulário ou variável de ambiente.
  - **STATUS:** Pode ser usado para executar um script, sem enviar uma nova página para o cliente. Também pode ser usado para enviar uma mensagem de erro ou outra informaçao para o cliente.
- O script deve ser executável pelo usuário que o servidor tem configurado. (Existe um usuário especial chamado "***NOBODY***" que é o usuário padrão para a maioria dos servidores Web. Você deve se certificar de que o usuário "***NOBODY***" ou o usuário para o qual o seu servidor está configurado para trabalhar, tem permissão para executar os seus scripts e ler/escrever em quaisquer arquivos que o script possa usar).

[Mais detalhes de **Segurança em Scripts CGI**](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/%7Emlbc/cursos/internet/cgi/security.html)

### Como obter informações do servidor?

Cada vez que um usuário solicita a URL correspondente ao seu programa **CGI**, o servidor irá executá-lo em tempo real.
Um conceito errado sobre **CGI** é que você pode enviar linhas de comandos opcionais e argumentos para seu programa, tal como:

`command% myprog -qa blorf`

**CGI** utiliza a linha de comando para outros propositos. Gateway usa variaveis de ambiente para enviar ao programa seus parametros.

**Exemplo das variáveis de ambiente do servidor do [DCC](http://www.dcc.ufmg.br/cgi-bin/test-cgi):**

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# disable filename globbing
set -f

echo "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"
echo

echo CGI/1.0 test script report:
echo

echo argc is $#. argv is "$*".
echo

echo SERVER_SOFTWARE = $SERVER_SOFTWARE
echo SERVER_NAME = $SERVER_NAME
echo GATEWAY_INTERFACE = $GATEWAY_INTERFACE
echo SERVER_PROTOCOL = $SERVER_PROTOCOL
echo SERVER_PORT = $SERVER_PORT
echo REQUEST_METHOD = $REQUEST_METHOD
echo HTTP_ACCEPT = "$HTTP_ACCEPT"
echo PATH_INFO = "$PATH_INFO"
echo PATH_TRANSLATED = "$PATH_TRANSLATED"
echo SCRIPT_NAME = "$SCRIPT_NAME"
echo QUERY_STRING = "$QUERY_STRING"
echo REMOTE_HOST = $REMOTE_HOST
echo REMOTE_ADDR = $REMOTE_ADDR
echo REMOTE_USER = $REMOTE_USER
echo AUTH_TYPE = $AUTH_TYPE
echo CONTENT_TYPE = $CONTENT_TYPE
echo CONTENT_LENGTH = $CONTENT_LENGTH
```

### Como enviar documentos para o usuário?

Programas **CGI** podem retornar um grande número de tipos de documentos. Podem retornar uma imagem ao usuário, um documento HTML, ou talvez um clip de áudio. Podem também referenciar outros documentos.

O cliente necessita saber que tipo de documento receberá, para que possa apresentá-lo de maneira adequada. Logo o programa **CGI** deve informar ao servidor que tipo de documento está sendo enviado.

De forma a comunicar ao servidor o tipo de documento que está retornando, se é um **documento completo** ou uma **referência** para outro, **CGI** requer um pequeno cabeçalho na saída. Este cabeçalho é um texto **ASCII**, consistindo de linhas separadas ou por ***linefeeds*** ou por ***carriage returns*** (ou por ambos) seguidos de uma linha em branco.

**Exemplo:**

- Um **documento completo** com o tipo MIME correspondente.

Enviando um documento HTML para o cliente.

```html
Content-type: text/html

<html>
<head>
    <title>saída HTML de um script CGI</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Saída de exemplo</h1>
    O que você acha <strong>disso?</strong>
</body>
</html>
```

Uma **referência** a outro documento.

```html
Content-type: text/html
Location: gopher://httprules.foobar.org/0

<html>
<head>
    <title>Desculpe...moveu-se</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ir para vez do Gopher</h1>
    Agora disponível em
    <a href="gopher://httprules.foobar.org/0">uma nova localização</a> no nosso servidor do Gopher.
</body>
</html>
```

### Como construir um formulário?

Um formulário pode ser criado dentro de uma página html usando a tag FORM. Uma página pode conter vários formulários, mas os formulários não podem estar contidos uns nos outros.

```html
<form method="Método GET ou POST" action="A URL">...</form>
```

Onde o ACTION é a URL do servidor que receberá os dados do formulário (isto é, é o endereço do programa CGI responsável pelo tratamento dos dados) e METHOD é a forma como os dados serão passados para o programa CGI.

Um formulário pode conter vários componentes, como *inputs*, *check boxes* e *radio*.

### Como obter os dados do formulário?

Existem dois métodos que podem ser usados para acessar os formulários, GET e POST. Dependendo do método utilizado, você receberá os dados de maneira diferente.

- O método **GET:** Se o seu formulário usa `method="GET"`, seu programa CGI receberá os dados codificados na variável de ambiente **QUERY_STRING**.

**Exemplo:**

```html
<form method="GET" action="get-query.cgi">
    Login: <input type="text" name="login" />
    Senha: <input type="text" name="senha" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

**get-query.cgi**

```c
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char *query;
   
   printf("Content-type: text/plain\n\n");
   /* METHOD="GET" */
   query=getenv("QUERY_STRING");
   printf("Os dados recebidos do formulário são:\n\n");
   printf("%s\n", query);

   return(0);
}
```

[Exemplo completo](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/%7Emlbc/cursos/internet/cgi/form-get.html)

- O método **POST:** Se o seu formulário usa `method="POST"`, seu programa CGI receberá os dados da entrada padrão stdin. O servidor NÃO enviará um EOF ao término dos dados. Ao invés disso você terá que usar a variável de ambiente **CONTENT_LENGTH** para determinar a quantidade de dados a serem lidos de stdin.

**Exemplo:**

```html
<form method="POST" action="post-query.cgi">
    Login: <input type="text" name="login" />
    Senha: <input type="text" name="senha" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

**post-query.cgi**

```c
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char *query;
   int  length;
   
   printf("Content-type: text/plain\n\n");
   /* METHOD="POST" */
   length=atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
   query=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1));
   if (query!=NULL)
      fread(query, length, sizeof(char), stdin);
   printf("Os dados recebidos do formulário são:\n\n");
   printf("%s\n\n", query);
   printf("A variável de ambiente CONTENT_LENGTH tem o valor %d.\n", length);

   return(0);
}
```

[Exemplo completo](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/%7Emlbc/cursos/internet/cgi/form-post.html)

Como fazer para ler uma variável de ambiente dependerá do Sistema Operacional em que o programa CGI será executado e da linguagem de programação em que foi escrito. Um programa C rodando em UNIX pode usar a função `char *getenv(const char *name);` que recebe o nome da variável como argumento e retorna o seu valor em um string.

## É uma tecnologia antiga?

O CGI foi concebido como o culminar de discussões por especialistas durante os primórdios da Internet, em 1993 pela NSCA(National Center for Supercomputing Applications) nomeadamente entre Rob McCool, John Franks, Ari Luotonen, George Phillips e Tony Sanders. O que pode fazer dela ser considerada uma tecnologia antiga.

Especificação do CGI 1.1: [RFC3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875)

Embora a linguagem tipicamente associada aos CGI seja o Perl, o CGI foi concebido de forma a ser independente da linguagem utilizada. Atualmente tecnologias como `ASP.NET`, `PHP`, `Python` e `Ruby` continuam a utilizar a especificação.

### Existem outras alternativas a ele(quais)?

- **FastCGI:** É um protocolo binário para interação de interfaces de programas com um Servidor Web.
- **PSGI:** É uma interface entre *servidores web* e *Aplicações web PERL* e *Frameworks* que permite escrever aplicações que podem ser executados como servidores autônomos ou usando o CGI.
- **Rack:** Fornece uma interface modular e adaptável para o desenvolvimento de aplicações web em Ruby.
- **WRB:** Tecnologia de servidor HTTP similar ao *CGI* distribuído pela Oracle.

Fontes:
http://penta.ufrgs.br/edu/forms/cgi.html
https://www.w3.org/CGI/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI
[http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~mlbc/cursos/internet/cgi/intro.htm](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/%7Emlbc/cursos/internet/cgi/intro.htm)

Comment: Gostei da resposta, o objetivo não é competir, mas detalhar o máximo, um assunto tão interessante... E você o fez...Só acho que essa definição :"Gateways são na realidade programas", não está correta... Posso estar errado, mas  acredito que não...https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway

Comment: Existe várias definições para Gateway, meu caro amigo. A wikipedia inglesa contém informações mais verdadeiras e limpas, aprendi isto com outros usuários mais avançados daqui: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway

Comment: Você também o fez, sua resposta está simplismente ótima, bastante detalhada

Comment: @ViníciusLima Discordo que neste caso a informação seja mais verdadeira e limpa. O termo Gateway, no mundo inteiro, faz referência a um nó da rede. Não é porque está na wiki/en que está correto.
Mas assim o texto é seu, se você acha que tá legal...Num muda naum... Personalidade é tudo...eu respeito...
Embora tenha 2 páginas entre 1 milhão, que faz uso do termo, eu ainda acho incorreto... Como eu disse, posso estar errado, embora eu não acredite... Se achar algum texto do Tanenbaum usando esse termo eu mudo de opinião na hora...

Comment: Desculpe-me, retirei do texto não precisava disso...

Comment: Oi Vinicius. Dei o bonus pra outra resposta, mas quero deixar claro que a sua está muito boa e votei positivo também. Fiquei bastante indeciso, mas eu tinha que decidir, e por uns pequenos detalhes optei por aquela, mas o importante é que mesmo o bônus não indo pra sua, ele atraiu votos para os dois (na verdade, ainda bem que deu muito mais que os 50 do bonus). Grato pela boa contribuição também.

Answer (score 7):

CGI é um método para que uma página Web seja gerada dinamicamente por um executável, em vez de ser um arquivo estático. Todo texto que o executável mandar para o "terminal", sairá na página. Nos primeiros tempos da Web, sem muitas preocupações com segurança, era comum que páginas dinâmicas fossem geradas até por scripts shell. Outro problema do CGI é que cada geração de página invoca um processo, o que pesa rápido num servidor com muitos acessos.