# Qual a diferença de usar o PHP como módulo do Apache, CGI, FastCGI e linha de comando?

Tags: php, fastcgi, cgi

Queria saber que diferença tem entre as várias "versões" ou "maneiras" de usar o PHP, pois tem o módulo do Apache, CGI, FastCGI e linha de comando. Então gostaria de saber se há alguma diferença ou "regra" pra qual devo usar e em qual situação.

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é CGI e qual é sua finalidade?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93308/91)

Comment: Diferença entre PHP e CGI?

Comment: não php-cgi eu tirei o - pq ele não tava deixando eu enviar a pergunta

Comment: Diferença em relação a que?

Comment: ao php normal php e php-cgi

Comment: não tem "PHP normal". Tem PHP cgi, fastcgi, PHP módulo, e PHP linha de comando. O PHP é o mesmo, o que muda é como interagir com ele. Apesar de fraquinha a resposta, tá explicado aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93308/91

Comment: ata muito obrigado

Comment: @ArthurPorto vou ver se acho alguma explicação melhor e já ponho o link. Pra falar a verdade, tá ruim a resposta do link indicado. Aqui tem alguma coisa também: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI - O importante é saber que no CGI, o servidor web repassa a requisição para um executável (no caso do PHP, é justamente o PHP cgi), e o que sair desse executável, é devolvido para o browser.

Comment: @ArthurPorto dei uma editada na sua pergunta pra tentar deixar ela mais específica pra PHP, e pus um bônus naquela outra pra quem puser uma resposta mais caprichada, assim, espero que em poucos dias você tenha uma resposta melhor, tanto aqui como lá. É que fim de semana é mais devagar o site mesmo.

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo, vlw

Answer (score 45, accepted):

<sup>**Nota:** Não são "versões" nem "maneiras"... são modos de execução. Vou tentar realçar as principais diferenças entre eles, vantagens e desvantagens de cada um. No sumário uma dica do ambiente ideal para cada um.</sup>

## Apache Module (mod_php)

Usando o `mod_php` para executar scripts PHP num servidor web, é sem duvida o método mais popular e durante muito tempo foi o modo de execução padrão nas implementações dum servidor web.

Ao utilizar o `mod_php` o interpretador do PHP é incorporado em cada processo do Apache gerado no servidor. Desta forma, cada processo do Apache é capaz de manusear e executar por si só os scripts PHP eliminando a necessidade de lidar com quaisquer processos externos, ao contrário do que acontece com CGI ou FastCGI.

Isto torna-se principalmente útil em web-sites com um elevado uso de PHP, por exemplo se utilizarmos WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, entre outros, dado que todos os pedidos podem ser manipulados pelo Apache.

Como o interpretador é iniciado com o Apache, isto permite que ele seja executado rapidamente, uma vez que pode armazenar em cache determinadas informações sem necessidade de repetir tarefas cada vez que um script é executado.

A grande desvantagem deste modo é que cada processo do Apache fica cada vez maior (consome mais memória e recursos do servidor). Mesmo que o Apache esteja a servir apenas conteúdos estáticos, como é o caso de imagens, dado que contém sempre o interpretador do PHP, o consumo de memória e recursos é sempre elevado.

**Vantagens**

- Código PHP executado pelo Apache;
- Não há necessidade de processos externos;
- Excelente desempenho em web-site/plataformas com  grande uso de PHP;
- Definições de configuração do PHP podem ser personalizadas dentro das diretivas do `.htaccess`.

**Desvantagens**

- Faz com que cada processo do Apache seja maior (mais RAM consumida);
- Carrega o interpretador de PHP mesmo que esteja a servir conteúdo estático (imagens);
- O servidor web fica como proprietário dos arquivos criados pelos *scripts* PHP ao invés do utilizador de sistema (com alterações à configuração dá para alterar).

## CGI

Execução de scripts PHP com uma aplicação CGI é a maneira original para execução de aplicações num servidor web, é muito ineficiente e raramente utilizado. Introduzido por volta de 1990 foi rapidamente considerado ineficiente para usar em outra coisa senão muito pequenos sites.

A vantagem do modo de execução CGI é o fato de manter a execução de código separada do servidor web, o que permite alguns benefícios de segurança adicionais. Por exemplo, um script de PHP com bugs ou falhas de segurança não afeta nenhum ficheiro fora do domínio em que se encontra (particularmente vantajoso para servidores de alojamento web. Isso também significa que o interpretador de PHP só é chamado quando necessário, permitindo assim que o conteúdo estático seja servido unicamente pelo servidor web.

A grande ineficiência do modo CGI é o fato do mesmo abrir um novo processo sempre que é necessário executar código PHP. Em web-sites/plataformas que fazem um elevado uso de PHP, fica-se rapidamente com os recursos do servidor consumidos.

**Vantagens**

- Melhor segurança do que o `mod_php` dado que a execução de código PHP fica isolada do servidor web.

**Desvantagens**

- Fraco desempenho.

## FastCGI

FastCGI foi introduzido como um meio termo entre o módulo do Apache e a aplicação CGI. Ele permite que os programas sejam executados por um interpretador fora do servidor web, incluindo os benefícios de segurança do modo CGI sem nenhuma das suas ineficiências.

Ao executar *scripts* PHP com FastCGI cada pedido é transmitido a partir do servidor web para FastCGI através de uma camada de comunicação. Isto permite uma maior escalabilidade dado que o servidor web e o intérprete PHP podem ser divididos pelos seus próprios ambientes do servidor. No entanto, um resultado semelhante pode ser obtido utilizando [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) à frente do Apache.

FastCGI tem também a vantagem de ser executado como o utilizador do sistema, o que faz como que o mesmo seja sempre o proprietário de todos e quaisquer ficheiros criados durante a execução de *scripts* PHP.

A desvantagem de executar o PHP com suporte a FastCGI é que as diretivas PHP definidas num ficheiro `.htaccess` não são respeitadas. Em alternativa, é possível definir as diretivas do PHP num ficheiro `php.ini`.

**Vantagens**

- Maior segurança, dada a execução de código PHP num ambiente isolado do servidor web;
- O conteúdo estático não é processado pelo interpretador PHP;
- Permite que os ficheiros sejam geridos pelo utilizador de sistema sem necessidade de alterar permissões.

**Desvantagens**

- Não é possível utilizar diretivas PHP no ficheiro `.htaccess`.

## PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager)

É uma implementação alternativa ao PHP FastCGI com algumas características adicionais úteis para web-sites de qualquer tamanho, especialmente para os mais pesados.

**Vantagens**

- Crescimento de processos de forma adaptativa;
- Estatísticas básicas (parecido com o *mod_status* do Apache);
- Gestão avançada de processos com inicio/paragem graciosa;
- Capacidade de iniciar os trabalhadores com diferentes *uid*, *gid*, *chroot*, ambiente e `php.ini` (substitui *safe_mode*)
- Cria logs para a stdout e stderr;
- Reinício de emergência em caso de destruição acidental de código (*cache*);
- Suporta upload acelerado;
- Diversas melhorias para a sua faceta FastCGI.

**Desvantagens**

- Até 2011 estava em versão experimental, atualmente a sua desvantagem é o seu pouco uso (poucas implementações face aos restantes modos PHP).

## CLI (linhas de comandos)

Este modo de execução é muito semelhante ao modo CGI, trazendo as seguintes vantagens face ao mesmo:

- Por padrão, não escreve cabeçalhos para o output;
- Algumas diretivas do `php.ini` são sobrescritas pelo CLI porque não fazem sentido no ambiente *shell*:

  - `html_errors`: padrão no CLI é FALSE
  - `implicit_flush`: padrão no CLI é TRUE
  - `max_execution_time`: padrão no CLI é 0 (ilimitado)
  - `register_argc_argv`: padrão no CLI é TRUE
- Permite passar argumentos da linha de comandos para o *script*;
- Temos acesso a 3 constantes definidas para o ambiente shell: `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, `STDERR`;
- Não altera a diretoria atual para a diretoria do *script* executado. Significa que a diretoria atual é onde digitamos o comando para executar o *script*.

Essencialmente, é uma forma de executar *scripts* PHP para realização de tarefas no servidor, quer com ficheiros, manipulação de dados, manutenção à base de dados e/ou outras coisas mais morosas ou pesadas que não podem correr via SAPI.

---

## Sumário

Para sumariar, cada modo de execução torna-se vantajoso para um cenário em particular como podemos observar na seguinte tabela:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────┐
│ Apache Module (mod_php)           │ Alto desempenho em           │
│                                   │ web-sites simples            │
├───────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│ CGI                               │ ...não utilizar...           │
│                                   │                              │
├───────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│ FastCGI                           │ Ideal para qualquer tipo     │
│                                   │ web-sites/aplicações         │
├───────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│ PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) │ Supostamente +vantajoso que  │
│                                   │ o FastCGI para qualquer tipo │
│                                   │ de web-sites/aplicações!     │
├───────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│ CLI (linhas de comandos)          │ Para scripts que realizam    │
│                                   │ tarefas no servidor          │
└───────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Ótima resposta, só fiquei com uma duvida, Apache Module se refere ao Apache2Handler?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não propriamente, o `Apache2Handler` pode não estar instalado. O modulo de Apache `mod_php` é apenas um dos muitos módulos presentes no Apache.

Comment: Entendo, é que penso eu que a ideia do AP era referente as maneiras de usar o PHP, talvez citar o apache2handler seria interessante (apesar de preferir o PHP-FPM), todavia já deixei o +1 garantido.