# O que é proxy reverso?

Tags: terminologia

Quando eu estava configurando o [PHP FPM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134473/4995) (modulo do PHP que permite o uso de FastCGI), esbarrei no termo *Reverse Proxy* quando eu andava pesquisando alguns tutoriais sobre como configurá-lo no Apache 2.

Exemplo tirado desse [site](http://www.binarytides.com/setup-apache-php-fpm-mod-proxy-fcgi-ubuntu/), onde é ensinado a instalar o módulo `mod_proxy_fcgi`:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/mysite/$1
```

Mas o que seria um Proxy Reverso? Eu já ouvi esse termo outras vezes, mas não entendi do que se trata.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para explicar o que é um Proxy Reverso, acho importante explicar também como ele difere do Proxy.

O **Proxy Reverso** (*Reverse Proxy*) é um proxy que podemos dizer que atua do lado do servidor, diferente do **Proxy** (*Forward Proxy*) que atua do lado do cliente.

O **Proxy** preocupa-se em esconder as identidades das máquinas que estão atrás dele, fornecendo mecanismos tais como *cache*, autenticação, restringir acessos para alguns sites, etc. Assim, quando algum computador dentro da uma rede fazer alguma requisição para Internet através do Proxy, este será encarregado de fazer a requisição, aguardar a resposta e encaminhá-la para o computador que a solicitou.

Já o **Proxy Reverso** faz o mesmo, mas para os servidores. Quando a requisição chega, o Proxy Reverso obtém aquela informação e a repassa para um dos servidores disponíveis, podendo [ser capaz](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/) de fazer *Load Balance*. Ele também pode fazer compressão dos dados, cache de conteúdo frequentemente requisitado, proteger as identidades dos servidores, permitir que eles sejam acessados sob uma única URL, etc.

Veja uma [imagem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46508865/2387977) ilustrando ambos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em sua essência, ambos são **muito** parecidos, tendo as mesmas características.

Não sei dizer se isto vale para todos os casos, mas de fato um mesmo proxy pode ser *forward* e *reverse* ao mesmo tempo, atendendo populações distintas. Ou seja, de diferente mesmo é só o papel que o proxy vai exercer conforme a necessidade: atender clientes ou servidores.

Answer (score 16):

Resposta rápida:

Proxy reverso seria um **serviço** ou servidor que encaminha  as requisições para outro **serviço/servidor** de forma transparente.  O cliente (navegador por exemplo) não sabe a existência desse segundo serviço.

No seu caso o serviço `httpd(apache)` estaria encaminhado o processamento de qualquer requisição contendo `.php` (é mais ou menos o que a expressão regular `^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)` quer dizer ) para o serviço fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000 (servidor local porta 9000).

Esse serviço por sua vez trata a requisição e a resposta usando o apache como um "proxy" para o cliente -- PROXY REVERSO.

Outra possível origem do nome é que normalmente o proxy é usado do lado dos clientes, então o "reverso" dá a ideia que está no outro lado, diferente do "normal".

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro é interessante entender o conceito do Proxy.
**O *Proxy*** é uma camada (*middleware*, *server*, qualquer implementação que crie essa camada) entre dois pontos.
Esse é um conceito mais amplo, pode ser aplicado em programas e outras coisas. Para o conceito da pergunta, um Proxy está intermediando dois dispositivos conectados na Internet, que podem ser dois computadores, dispositivo (impressora, gadget, etc), etc.

Qual a razão para usar esse intermediário entre as conexões? Os motivos são diversos:

- proteger os dispositivos e suas identidades;
- proteger a rede a qual eles fazem parte;
- restringir/bloquear acessos indevidos, etc;

Então um ***Proxy Forward*** (de encaminhamento) ou simplesmente ***Proxy***, é um *middleware*, que pode ser um software ou um hardware que está a frente da conexão de um computador ou dispositivo com outro.
A figura abaixo, tirada do Cloudfire, demostra isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que, vários computadores numa rede tem à sua frente um ***Proxy***, que faz o intermédio entre eles e um recurso da internet, um servidor por exemplo. As razões podem ser diversas, como as mencionadas acima, como proteger a identidade do computador de origem, ou ainda filtrar o que pode “sair” para a internet, bloqueando acesso a sites adultos ou upload de arquivos por exemplo. Então vamos imaginar o Proxy como

> “*A camada que está a frente do computador origem e o destino que esse
>   quer acessar.*”

Já essa outra imagem mostra o diagrama de um Proxy Reverso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que é basicamente o mesmo, os propósitos também podem ser, mas nesse caso o ***Proxy*** está a frente do recurso de destino, ou seja,

> “*A camada que está a frente do computador de destino, e a origem que precisa acessá-lo.*”

Dai o conceito de “inverso”, um está logo após a origem, o outro antes de destino, de uma maneira bem simples é isso que significa.

Answer (score 2):

Um proxy reverso é um servidor de rede geralmente instalado para ficar na frente de um servidor Web. Todas as conexões originadas externamente são endereçadas para um dos servidores Web através de um roteamento feito pelo servidor proxy, que pode tratar ele mesmo a requisição ou encaminhar a requisição toda ou parcialmente a um servidor Web, que tratará dela
Uma das maiores caracteristicas dos proxy reverso é a sua segurança que faz com que seja mais dificil penetrar no servidor, criptografia em SSL

Espero que te tenha tirado as duvidas