# Existe diferenças entre Post e Request?

Tags: post, terminologia, request

Quando eu [leio](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) a respeito do **request** sempre me aparece o termo **post** junto, e isso me gera uma dúvida. Eu compreendo que o **request** serve para fazer um pedido de algo para o servidor e depois o servidor envia uma resposta após processar o tal pedido, e ao ler a respeito do **post** me parece que ele faz a mesma coisa, e é neste ponto que gera a dúvida, eu não consigo entender a diferença entre eles.

---

## Pergunta

Eu gostaria de saber se existe diferença entre **Request** e **Post**, caso exista, gostaria de saber quais são as principais diferenças entre eles e também a principal finalidade do **Post**?

<sup>*Fiquem a vontade para dar exemplos práticos em qualquer linguagem de programação caso queiram.*</sup>

Comment: Será que a tua duvida é entre Post e Get? Ou ambas?

Comment: @Sergio estou estudando Http, ainda sei sei o que é Get, se para entender a diferença entre Post e Request seja necessário entender o que é Get, pode explicar sobre ele tbm :).

Comment: Algumas coisas relacionadas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118213/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93308/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9419/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92870/101

Comment: post e um metodo de requisicao existe outros varios tipos de de metodo como get put header se voce quiser vc pode ate criar o seu acho qu e isso requisicao e o que todos clientes http fazem entre outros protocolo agora post e so um metodo dessa requisicao voce pode testar suas requisicoes nesse site https://httpbin.org/

Comment: No PHP pelo menos, `$_POST` é os dados vindo do formulário (método `POST`). `$_REQUEST` é a mistura dos dados `Post`, `Get`, `Cookie`. É a primeira coisa que vem a mente :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O ***request*** é uma forma genérica de se referir ao assunto, podemos usar a tradução que será tão bem ou melhor entendido que é uma requisição de informação ao servidor. Tem diversas maneiras de realizar uma requisição. O termo poderia ser usado em outros contextos e indicar a mesma coisa, ele não tem um significado específico na tecnologia, é só uma palavra necessária para dar entendimento ao que está sendo usado. Nesse contexto é uma requisição usando HTTP.

Em HTTP, entre as diversas formas de realizar a requisição, tem o verbo usado para requisitá-lo. Cada verbo tem sua semântica própria de funcionar. Um desses verbos é o **`POST`**. Então esse termo é uma forma bem específica, com regras próprias de como fazer a requisição. Então esse é um termo com significado técnico definido em especificação.

Eu dei uma [resposta diferenciando sobre `POST` e `PUT` que mostra os principais detalhes do `POST`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92870/101).

Tem outra com [informações básicas sobre os demais verbos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9419/101). E a [importância de usar os verbos corretos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322/101). Todos esses verbos são *métodos de requisição*.

Pode entender melhor todo esse funcionamento na [pergunta sobre CGI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93308/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Complementado a resposta com um exemplo em `PHP`.

---

**POST**

O `post` utiliza a URI (*Uniform Resource Identifier*) para envio de informações ao servidor, que por não ser retornável ao cliente, torna o método mais seguro, pois assim não expões os dados enviados no navegador.

A partir do `post` é criada toda a estrutura do formulário necessária para o funcionamento das aplicações web. Com ele é possível obter os dados de um determinado campo:

```
<FORM NAME=”form1″ METHOD=”post” ACTION=”pagina.php”>
   Campo 1:
   <INPUT TYPE=”text” NAME=”campo1″>
   <BR>
   Campo 2:
   <TEXTAREA NAME=”campo2″></TEXTAREA>
   <BR>
   <INPUT TYPE=”submit” VALUE=”Enviar”>
</FORM>

<?php
   echo(“O valor do primeiro campo é ” . $_POST[‘campo1’]);
   echo(“O valor do segundo campo ” . $_POST[‘campo2’]);
?>
```

**REQUEST**

`$_REQUEST`, por padrão, contém o conteúdo do `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`. Ele é chamado de coleção genérica, pois nele é retornado o valor da 
variável, de acordo com a configuração do arquivo `php.ini`:

```
<FORM NAME=”form1″ METHOD=”post” ACTION=”pagina.php?x=1″>
   <INPUT TYPE=”text” NAME=”txtCampo1″ VALUE=”Valor do Campo Texto”>
   <INPUT TYPE=”submit” VALUE=”Enviar”>
</FORM>

<?php
   echo($_REQUEST[‘v’]);
?>
```

Veja essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924958/5327226) do stackoverflow em inglês.

Referências:

- [Diferença entre os métodos GET e POST](http://professortorres.com.br/diferenca-entre-os-metodos-get-e-post/)
- [GET, POST, REQUEST](http://www.scriptcase.com.br/blog/get-post-request-php/)