# Qual é a primeira linguagem de programação ou tecnologia usada para páginas dinâmicas?

Tags: http

Procurei muito a respeito do assunto, li sobre a história voltada ao front-end, como o início do *JavaScript®* (Mozilla/Netscape), mas realmente fiquei curioso a respeito do back-end e realmente não consigo encontrar algo claro, mesmo no Wikipédia.

Hoje temos diversas linguagens ou tecnologias que incorporam o controle do HTTP (requisição e resposta), no entanto gostaria de saber qual(is) foram a(s) primeira(s) *"linguagem(ens)"* ou *"tecnologia(s)"* a ser(em) utilizada(s) no back-end de páginas web?

Comment: Eu posso quase garantir que foi C, mas é por pura análise, não por informação que eu sei. Se o servidor HTTP que primeiro implementou CGI que permitiu criar páginas dinâmicas foi escrito em C, pelo menos para testar deve ter sido usado a mesma linguagem. Na verdade não sei se isto tem relevância, ou se pode ser respondido, até porque não se sabe nem quando a web foi criada, dependendo do critério é 1989, 1990 ou 1993. Mesmo que se saiba qual foi a primeira, o que isso ajuda?

Comment: @bigown perdão, eu que li errado. Eu só formulei a pergunta por questão de ter no site, no geral eu já "sabia" (se eu estiver correto) que CGI foi uma das primeiras a ser implementada para isto, é o mesmo tipo de pergunta que alguns fazem aqui, mais por curiosidade do que por utilidade.

Comment: CGI não é linguagem. A questão não é ser curioso ou não. É que saber qual foi a primeira linguagem usada não serve para nada.  Não tem isto escrito em algum lugar da web porque ninguém precisa saber disto.  Não vai informar melhor, não vai acabar com uma boa prática cega, não fará ninguém usr algo melhor, não dará um fundamento, não ajudará entender porque usamos algo de determinada forma.

Comment: @bigown entendi, eu escrevi uma coisa no corpo da pergunta e outra no titulo -.- ... fail, um instante. Corrigido para ficar igual ao que foi escrito no corpo. Se é útil? Tenho certeza que não, assim como muitas outras perguntas, mas se acharem necessário eu voto pra fechar, talvez off-topic.

Comment: @bigown Essa informação pode não ter uso prático imediato, mas é uma pergunta sobre história da tecnologia. Nunca discutimos isso no meta, mas eu acho válido. Sei que pode ser polêmico.

Comment: @bfavaretto se fosse sobre história mesmo, a informação estaria disponível. Como está qual foi a primeira linguagem. Isso importa, isso tem consequências importantes na evolução? Só é história o que é relevante. Só porque aconteceu não é história.

Comment: Vixe @bigown melhor não discutirmos aqui sobre o conceito de história hehehe.

Answer (score 10):

### História:

- **A web pré-1994**

Quando a Internet se tornou user-friendly (amigo do usuário), nos anos 90, não existia aquilo a que hoje chamamos de back-end. A Internet da época, continha formas básicas de código HTML, que eram acessadas por um computador que fazia a ligação (muitas vezes lenta) ao servidor onde o site estava alojado. (Internet discada)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma Internet feita de HTML básico significava que os utilizadores apenas podiam ver as páginas estáticas, como elas eram construídas, ao contrário de hoje, onde as páginas são populadas por conteúdos dinâmicos. Não havia a possibilidade de visitar sites com output de HTML customizado.

- **CGI & o Nascimento do Desenvolvimento Back-end**

Felizmente, os anos de 93 e 94 trouxeram consigo o CGI ([Common Gateway Interface](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI)), permitindo aos browsers interagirem diretamente com os servidores, executando os pedidos em tempo real, trabalhando a informação de forma dinâmica.

- [O que é CGI e qual é sua finalidade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93308/o-que-%C3%A9-cgi-e-qual-%C3%A9-sua-finalidade)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que os pedidos exigem processamento em background e execução de várias aplicações. É por isto que o atual desenvolvimento back-end é tão importante. Ao contrário do desenvolvimento front-end, que é responsável por tudo aquilo que o utilizador vê, o desenvolvimento back-end permite que a gestão da base de dados e processamento no servidor aconteça nos bastidores, longe dos olhares dos utilizadores, mas que são essenciais para a interação entre os vários níveis de informação presente no site.

- **Qual é a linguagem de programação dos CGI**

Historicamente, os scripts CGI eram frequentemente escritos usando a [linguagem C](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)). [RFC3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875) define parcialmente CGI usando C.

Um programa CGI pode ser escrito em quase todas as linguagens de programação desde que ele possa ler o fluxo de dados de entrada, processar cadeias de caracteres (strings), gravar sobre o fluxo padrão de saída e que seja executável ou que pode ser interpretado pelo servidor web.

As linguagens de programação mais utilizadas para a gravação dos CGI são a linguagem Perl, particularmente adaptada à manipulação de cadeias de caracteres, as linguagens C++ e a linguagem Java.

[image: Arvore]
[Fonte](http://slideplayer.com.br/slide/2263429/) (*Não abrange todas*)

**As linguagens mais usadas juntamente com o CGI:**

- C/C++
- PERL
- TCL
- Bourne Shell, C Shell (em ambiente UNIX)
- VB Script (em ambiente Windows)

---

### O que é Back-end

[image: Codigo]

É o que acontece na parte de "trás" da aplicação. Em termos gerais, a implementação da regra de negócio, funcionamento e tudo mais.

Com isso temos o famoso desenvolvedor back-end, este desenvolvedor, quando focado, não toca na parte visual da aplicação. Por lidar com a regra de negócio, as vezes um programador de sistemas, como de aplicações comerciais e até científicas, pode ser chamado de desenvolvedor back-end.

Quando falamos de back-end em desenvolvimento web, nos deparamos com várias linguagens, cada uma possui vantagens e desvantagens em relação ao uso no desenvolvimento web, bem como no mercado de trabalho.

[image: Definição]

---

Algumas Linguagens Back-end atualmente:

- Perl *Catalyst*
- Ruby on Rails
- .NET
- ASP
- C♯
- VB
- Java
- JSP
- PHP
- Python

---

**Curiosidades:**

Você pode acompanhar o ranking das linguagens mais utilizadas (Front e Back) em https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/

Referências bibliográficas:

- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_e_back-end
- https://www.fabiolobo.com.br/o-que-e-front-end-e-back-end.html
- http://tableless.github.io/iniciantes/manual/obasico/o-que-front-back.html
- https://www.kwan.pt/pt/blog/back-end-dev
- [https://web.fe.up.pt/~goii2000/M9/linguagens.htm](https://web.fe.up.pt/%7Egoii2000/M9/linguagens.htm)

Comment: Achei a resposta interessantíssima, mas eu perdi algo ou ela não responde "Qual a primeira linguagem de programação usada para páginas dinamicas?"?

Comment: @bigown fiz uma melhoria no trecho "Qual é a linguagem de programação dos CGI"

Comment: O senhor merece uma internet (e uma recompensa).

Answer (score 7):

**Resposta rápida**: uma combinação de C, Perl e Shell script.

**Resposta longa**:

É difícil precisar sobre o início da geração de páginas dinâmicas porque o termo só faz sentido depois que a internet se espalhou e tais páginas se tornaram relevantes. Entretanto, sabe-se que mesmo antes do CGI, e até mesmo do HTML, já existia a geração de conteúdo dinâmico nas [redes TBBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#History).

Com o advento da internet, foi criado o padrão CGI (Common Gateway Interface / Interface de Entrada Padrão) que visava ser a porta de comunicação entre o servidor e o cliente. Como os scripts CGI eram geralmente escritos [em C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#History), esta linguagem foi utilizada, em conjunto com [Perl e Shell Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Explanation), para o processamento no lado do servidor.