# Tem como aplicar HTML/CSS em um programa em C puro?

Tags: html, css, c, aplicação-web

O clube de programação a que estou participando concluiu um programa que funciona como um controlador de estoque e mostra as coisas que estão disponíveis e as coisas emprestadas.

Foi feito em C puro, de modo que a exibição é bastante arcaica,

Parece com isto: | Controle 1 | Disponível |

E eu estou pensando se eu poderia fazer algo assim:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid transparent; border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;    
    width: 100%; 
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    padding: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

table, th{background-color: lightBlue; }

td{background-color: steelBlue;border-radius: 0px;}

#ultimo {border-bottom-left-radius: 0;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Controle 1</th>
    <td>Disponível</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Controle 2</th>
    <td>Emprestado</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Controle 3</th>
    <td>Disponível</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Controle 4</th>
    <td>Emprestado</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Controle 5</th>
    <td>Disponível</td>
</tr>
<tr id="ultimo">
    <th>Controle 6</th>
    <td>Disponível</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Então é muito pouco interativo, e toda vez que há uma mudança na página (como algo emprestado), a página precisa ser atualizada.

A questão é: eu teria alguma maneira de usar o programa em uma interface renderizada em HTML - e CSS, melhor ainda - ou seja, use c como um JSP (ou PHP ou JS ainda não dominava essa área). Claro, seria muito mais viável traduzir essa ideia para outra linguagem, mas nosso objetivo é aprender o máximo possível do idioma, e fazer isso seria uma grande conquista!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim e não. C consegue emitir textos para onde você quiser do jeito que quiser. Servidores HTTP recebem textos de qualquer tecnologia que desejar desde que cumpra certos padrões, principalmente o [CGI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93308/101) (um pouco ultrapassado) ou alguma outra forma de comunicar com o servidor, que por sinal deve ter sido desenvolvido em C ou C++ (hoje isso já é menos verdade em alguns casos), então é muito fácil eles se falarem por meios que não sejam textos diretos. Aí é escolher a forma que desejar fazer a comunicação, estudar seus protocolos e fazer o C interagir de acordo.

O C em si, puro como está dizendo, não tem algo pronto para isso, ainda mais com facilidades em que você monta um arquivo que será interpretado pela aplicação e fará algo sem nenhuma preocupação adicional. Existem bibliotecas que podem ajudar nisso em menor ou maior grau.

Mas já adianto que a maioria das pessoas não usa C para fazer algo web, não é uma linguagem muito produtiva. Em geral C é usado pra fazer sistemas operacionais, servidores, *drivers*, programação embarcada, ou outras coisas que precisa o máximo de performance, controle do hardware e manipulação de memória. Mesmo algumas coisas que precisam disso tudo, mas não no extremo, usam C++. Há um pouco mais de tentativas de uso de web em C++, mas pouco. O grosso é usado Java, C#, PHP, e coisas do tipo.

Eu não me preocuparia em tentar fazer isso em C, até porque se dominar C como deve, e poucas pessoas que começam o fazem, a gente vê aqui o tempo todo o pessoal aprendendo C tudo errado, fazer algo pra web é o de menos, é algo quase burocrático.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).