# Python com CGI e WEB

Tags: python, apache, cgi

Fiz um codigo simples em python que exibe em uma pagina web a versão do sistema operacional do usuário e configurei meu web server que roda em linux para ser compativel com CGI.  Meu webServer roda em uma maquina Windows.

```
    import cgi, cgitb 
    import platform

    form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
    print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
    print "<html>"
    print "<head>"

    plataforma = platform.system()
    versao = platform.release()
    sistema= plataforma+" "+versao

    print "<h2>Seu sistema operacional e %s</h2>" % (sistema)
    print "</head>"
    print "<body>"
    print "</body>"
    print "</html>"
```

É algo bem simples só para eu entender o funcionamento do CGI com python, porem quando eu abro essa pagina em uma maquina Linux por exemplo, me da a mensagem que eu uso a versao do windows do meu Web Server.

Minha pergunta é, o CGI é executado no servidor e não no cliente?  Por exemplo, um codigo em python no mesmo estilo que faça o download de um arquivo, ele faria o download para o servidor e não para o cliente? Tem alguma outra forma de fazer o CGI rodar localmente ou teria que usar outra metodologia?

Comment: Você entende como o protocolo HTTP funciona?

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93308/101